# Getting too many rows when joining two tables together in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in MySQL: "student" and "department". They have the following schemas:

```
STUDENT->STU_ID(PRIMARY_KEY),STU_NAME,DEP_ID(FORIEGN_KEY);

DEPARTMENT->DEP_ID(P_K),DEP_NAME
```

I want to use `like` operator on `stu_name` and it's `dep_name` should be print instead of `dep_id`

I use the following query in PHP:

```
$sql_sel = mysqli_query(
     $conn,
     "SElECT * FROM STUDENT 
        WHERE STU_NAME like '%mykey%' 
        JOINS department ON student.dep_id=department.dep_id
     ");
```

However, if there is one student matching with `mykey`, then it prints the student name for every department. so if one student matching with n no. of department so n rows.

Comment: Did you think it would help if you write all in caps?

Comment: That select statement can't be working... where clause before the join?!  perhaps: `$sql_sel=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Stu_Name, DEP_NAME FROM STUDENT INNER JOIN department ON student.dep_id=department.dep_id WHERE STU_NAME like '%mykey%'");`

Answer (score 0):

First try

INNER JOIN

second

try adding

GROUP BY